# How to install J2EE plugin into Eclipse Luna SE

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have downloaded and installed eclipse luna for Java Dvelopers. I want to convert it into "eclipse luna for J2EE developers"..

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

The above link shows WTP3.1.1 and WTP 3.1.2 which is incompatible for Luna..

Can anybody suggest me?

Comment: Everything is available in the main Luna install site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna which should already be in your list of update sites.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to download Eclipse IDE for JAVA EE developers.

Go to this site and download that

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar

Comment: You don't have to download a separate install, you can install the missing pieces from the Lina update site.

Answer (score 18):

To install all plugins of WTP, compatible with Luna, you have to select the software site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna instead of the WTP site.

Here select at `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development`
the plugins included in WTP 3.1.2, but up to date:

- Axis2 Tools  1.1.300.v201405061940-78-FPZDZRDKYKDReDDRe
- Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support    3.4.1.v201409111648
- Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Support    3.4.0.v201405081709-7V7dEpFC7sReAYthMgWBL39c7
- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools  3.6.1.v201409042158
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.6.1.v201409111852
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools    3.6.1.v201409111852
- Eclipse XSL Developer Tools  1.3.401.v201409111855
- JavaScript Development Tools 1.6.100.v201409111605
- JSF Tools - Tag Library Metadata (Apache Trinidad)   2.5.0.v201405281344-23-7w312516392455
- JSF Tools - Web Page Editor  2.6.1.v201409111805

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, as I did  not want to migrate to a new IDE, plugins are perfect for me

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam: this answer is over a year old. Do you still use Luna - probably u're using Mars instead? If so the plugins will sure need versions which are up to date to be compatible with newer versions of eclipse.

Comment: @Marvin Emil Brach the jbpm automatically downloaded eclipse luna only with ant install.demo command. I already downloaded related plugins from download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna/. Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: @RaviKumarRavanam so it works now for you if I understand you correctly? If not, then describe your problem, so we are able to help you further :)